# same directory name as in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

i have a directory named target in my java project and want to ignore maven `target` directory in my `.gitignore`. But it also ignores a project directory with the same name, here is my `.gitignore`

```
.idea/
target/
out/
```

How can i have a directory as same as the one that is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way, in my opinion is to specify exceptions, in your .gitignore:

```
*target*

# exceptions
!/path/to/your/target
```

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is to add forward slash in your `.gitignore` as follows:

```
.idea/
/target/
out/
```

now it will only catch the directory name from project root.